# How to solve for a function an equation with integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What methods are there for solving for a function an equation that involves its integral?
Specifically, I am interested in knowing whether there is a function $f$ satisfying the equation 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}=\int_{t}^1\frac{rf(r)}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}}dr
\end{align}
For all $0\leq t \leq 1$ (and I am not concerned whether $f$ tends to infinity in the edges).

Thanks!

Comment: "Solve"... **for what** ? For $\;t\;$ ? Perhaps you'll have to give more info about that $\;f(r)\;$ there...

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant solving for $f$, that is finding an $f$ that solves the equation, or saying if no such $f$ exists. I'll edit

Comment: Well, $\;f(r)=1\;$ is a rather trivial solution. With it you get $\;t=\frac{\sqrt3}2\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant for all the $t$ in the range $0\leq t \leq 1$, edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: if there's a function $\;f\;$ for which the right hand integral is solvable then it'll clearly (imo) be a function of $\;t\;$ . Since the left hand side of the equation is a constant this will always give us a fixed value of $\;t\;$ , which I suppose will vary according to what $\;f\;$ was used. What do you mean " for all $\;t\in[0,1]\;$" ? Where is this exercise from? Differential calculus, physics...?

Comment: The function $f$ cannot be continue in $x=1$. I have tried $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. WolframAlpha has given to me that a primitive of $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}$ is $\displaystyle -\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{1-x²}}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}})$. This gives apparently that $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is a solution.

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant what I wrote, I want to know if there is a function $f$ which is only a function of $r$ that satisfies the above equation for all $t$ in the given range (notice that both the boundaries of integration and the integrand change as $t$ varies). I am aware that it is possible that no such function exists.

Comment: @Kelenner The function $\;f(r)=1\;$ , which I mentioned in a past comment, seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: @DonAntonio But $f(r)=1$ does not satisfy the equation for all the values $0 \leq t \leq 1$ simultaneously...

Comment: @GalPorat Well, I don't understand what you want/meant. I gave you an example with $\;f(r)=1\;$, from which we get $\;\sqrt{1-t^2}=\frac12\;$ . How this, or **any other result**, is going to be valid *for all* $\;t\in[0,1]\;$ is beyond my comprehension as "the result" is going to be a function of $\;t\;$ ... Perhaps someone else...

Comment: @Kelenner Yes: it is a function of $\;t\;$ , as any other possible value for the right hand integral, as far as I can see. But maybe I'm just missing something in this problem.

Comment: @Kelenner I think your solution is correct! (as I wrote above, I am fine with $f$ not being continuous at $1$) Perhaps you should write is as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ cannot be continuous in $x=1$. I have tried $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. WolframAlpha has given to me that a primitive of $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}$ is $\displaystyle -\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{1-x²}}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}})$. This gives apparently that $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is a solution. But of course this does not gives that this is the only solution.